# Detect file encoding in PHP without loading the whole file in memory

Tags: php, file, memory, encoding, utf-8

I want to read and process large (several hundred MB) files using PHP.

The files can be UTF-8 (with or without BOM) or ISO-8859-1 encoded.

Considering the size, the file needs to be streamed. The standard `mb_detect_encoding()` function requires the entire file to be loaded.

Is there any way to detect whether a file is UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 encoded (or, if possible, encoded some other way) without loading the entire file in memory?

Comment: 1. why can't you just read the first bytes into a buffer and feed that into `mb_detect_encoding()`? 2. `mb_detect_encoding()` is totally unreliable, itonly considers the first 500 characters! (no joke) Sorry to say so, but there simply is no reliable way to detect that. The simple reason: every file is a valid iso (8-bit) enoded file. The only thing you can reliably state is if a file is definitely _not_ a valid utf encoded file. But again: this might require to read the whole file, since 99.9% of the file might not contain any invalid utf sequences...

Comment: ^ I second @arkascha's remark that `mb_detect_encoding()` is only good for detecting what something is _not_, but it's all around terrible at guessing what it is (and often, multiple guesses may be correct). Even when supplying a decent `encoding_list`.